# The max number in a randomly generated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math

So this is what I have so far:

```js
function pirmaUzduotis() {
  var answer = [];
  var c = 0;
  answer[c] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) - 35;
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="pirmaUzduotis()">Click me</button>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

```js
function antraUzduotis() {
  var answer2 = [];
  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  for (b = 0; b < 20; b++) {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) - 35;
    answer2[b] = a;
  }
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answer2;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="antraUzduotis()">Click me</button>
<p id="answer2"></p>
```

So the first one is just an extra, the main focus is, the randomly generated array. I wish to create a button that on click shows me the highest number in the array. I mainly attempting to use `Math.max`. Here's what I have so far:

```js
function treciaUzuotis() {
  var array = arr;
  var array = answer3
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

}
document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = answer3
```

```html
<button onclick="treciaUzduotis()">Click me</button>

<p id="answer3"></p>
```

I believe my biggest problem is identifying the array as a variable. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: var numbers = [];
        for(i=1;i<10;i++){
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+10 - +1)) + +1;
           numbers.push(random);
        }
        console.log(numbers);
        alert(Math.max(...numbers));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the value of array from antraUzduotis

JS Code

```
<script>
    function antraUzduotis() {
        var answer2 = [];
        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;
        for (b = 0; b < 20; b++) {
            a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) - 35;
            answer2[b] = a;
        }
        return answer2;

    }
    function treciaUzduotis() {
        document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = Math.max.apply(null, antraUzduotis());
    }
</script>
```

Html Code

```
  <button onclick="treciaUzduotis()">Click me</button>
  <p id="answer3"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store you array of random numbers globally, you will access it later in with the `findMax` function.

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/Syntaxe_d%C3%A9composition) with the [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/max) to pass all the random number at the function.

```js
var answer2 = []; // store the array globaly

// fill it up with random values
function antraUzduotis() {

  var a = 0;
  var b = 0;
  for (b = 0; b < 20; b++) {
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 76) - 35;
    answer2[b] = a;
  }
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answer2;

}

// then you can access it in another function
function findMax() {
  document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = Math.max(...answer2);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="antraUzduotis()">Generate Random</button>
<button onclick="findMax()">Find Max</button>
<div> Randoms : <span id="answer2"></span></div>
<div> Max : <span id="max"></span></div>
```